# Animating the background color over an image on Safari is choppy

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a `background-color` over an image. It works fine on any browser/OS combination except Safari on macOS. I don't know if there's a workaround or a solution for this problem but I couldn't find any information on it while searching SO or Google.

Below is an example, you should try it on Safari. You'll also find a gif of the problem right under it, for those of us who don't own a mac.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300');
}

.img::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #AD00D2;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
}

.container:hover .img::before {
  background-color: #AD00D2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.text::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(280deg, #F12958, #AD00D2);
  background: linear-gradient(170deg, #F12958, #AD00D2);
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text">Text content</div>
</div>
```

[image: gif example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a pretty simple solution: remove the `.text::before` rule and replace it with a background on the `text` element.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300');
}

.img::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #AD00D2;
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
}

.container:hover .img::before {
  background-color: #AD00D2;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(280deg, #F12958, #AD00D2);
  background: linear-gradient(170deg, #F12958, #AD00D2);
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text">Text content</div>
</div>
```